# Waveguide modes: does a particular mode only propagate for one particular frequency?

Tags: waves, frequency, resonance, waveguide

I am trying to understand modes in a cylindrical dielectric waveguide. Does a particular mode only propagate for one particular frequency? Or, does a mode exist simply as long as the signal is above the cut-off frequency?

Basically, if I propagate a signal of a single frequency down the waveguide (a frequency that I know corresponds to the peak resonance of some mode), will I excite only that one mode?

Answer (score 2):

Transverse (TE and TM) modes in a recangular waveguide typically have dispersion equations $\omega(k_z)$  of the form
$$
\omega^2= ak_z^2 + \omega^2_{\rm min},
$$
where $a$ and $\omega_{\rm min}$ depend on the mode and the geometry of the waveguide and $z$ is the direction down the waveguide.
So, yes, once the frequency $\omega$ is greater that $\omega_{\rm min}$, there will be some real wavenumber $k_z$ for  which the mode will propagate at the given frequency. For frequencies lower than $\omega_{\rm min}$ the wavenumber $k_z$ will be imaginary, and so the mode will be evanescent.

Comment: so is it that a mode will propagate at any frequency above that cut-off frequency, but it might be more strongly excited (greater resonance) for some frequencies than others?

Comment: The extent to which a given mode is excited by a source depends on the impedence matching. In TE and TM dispersive modes  the  impedence does depend strongly on the frequency near $\omega_{\rm min}$ as you can read here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_impedance. The impedence does not depend on the frequency in non-dispersive TEM modes such as in a coaxial cable.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'm afraid I'm not managing to wrap my head around this. Will a signal with a single frequency excite one mode or all modes with a lower cut-off frequency than it?

Comment: In general a signal of a given frequency  will excite all modes, and will radiate down the waveguide those all modes that are above their cutoff frquency.  The modes will propagate at different speeds which is why one uses the non-dispersive TEM in coax if you want to send data. If you  wish to propagate  a single TE mode, for example, it will have to be the one with the lowest cutoff freqency.

Comment: Okay, I believe I understand - thank you kindly!